# Prove that if $X$ is a Hilbert space, then $B(X)$ is not a Hilbert space

Tags: hilbert-spaces

I`m having a homework question that goes like this: X is a Hilbert space, a complete inner product space, show that B(X) is not a Hilbert space.

I`m quite stuck and I would love to understand this problem!

My attempt so far:

Let $T \in B(X)$ be a linear operator, $\exists M > 0$ such that $||Tx|| \leq M||x||$, $\forall x \in X$. ( $T: X \rightarrow X$)

$T_n$ is a Cauchy sequence in $B(X)$ such that $T_n \rightarrow T$.

I think I have to show that $B(X)$ is not complete under the norm $||x||=\sqrt{(x,x)}$, so show that $B(X)$ is open. I can also show that the parallelogram law isn`t satisfied, but I don`t see how.

Proof:
$\forall \epsilon > 0 $, $\exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $||T_n-T|| < \epsilon $.
Also we have $||T_nx-Tx|| \leq ||T_n-T||||x|| < \epsilon||x||$ $\forall, x \in X$.

I dont know how to get further, please help!

Comment: $B(X)$ will always be complete if $X$ is. Your only hope is to show that the parallelogram law fails. In general this is not true, e.g. $X = \mathbb{R}$. I guess, you have to assume $\dim(X) \geq 2$ to make it work.

Comment: And $||x||=\sqrt{(x,x)}$ is the norm in $X$.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can the induced matrix norms be induced by inner products?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/317198/can-the-induced-matrix-norms-be-induced-by-inner-products)

Comment: I`m sorry I still dont get it! Could you give me more information please?